# Why is generated different traffic for the same attack?

Tags: network, metasploit, shellcode

I created a scenario in VirtualBox (configured as internal network) with two machines:  Windows XP and Kali Linux.
I used ms08_067_netapi exploit from Metasploit and the payload windows/meterpreter/reverse_tcp.
I tested the scenario two times (with 1 repetition) with exactly  the same configurations, however I noticed the traffic generated is different.

**Example:**

Look at these traffic examples:

Attempt 1: 
[image]
Attempt 2:
[image]

Make sense for why network ports can be different. But, as it is possible to see, the packet length is variable, and i don't understand why.

What is the reason why traffic is different if the attack is exactly the same? What can be the possible root cause?

Note:
In the link https://we.tl/t-hEVze7d0L4 is possible to check samples on pcap format (they are not the same from the pictures I mentioned, but the attacks are the same). I also included Snort IDS output for the different pcap files, and as it is possible to see were triggered alerts with different attributes for the same attacks.

Comment: it would be nice if you could upload both samples on pcap format, so every one can see exactly the traffic and the attack

Comment: @camp0 I have just included a link with the pcap files.

Comment: I think your problem is described here https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/24501/why-would-tcp-full-window-happen nothing related to the attack that you are making, I think.